# submitting a programatically change form action from within updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I'm confused... I have a form on my aspx page which the text fields sit inside an update panel. I use this to validate a login. If the login is successful, I change the form action and I want the form to then submit to that url.

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
               <!--form fields-->
               <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  onclick="btnSubmit_click" Text="Continue" />
          </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Then my codebehind

```
 protected void btnSubmit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //do some validation, if ok then change the form action
      form1.Action = "myurl2.aspx";
      btnSubmit = "proceed to next url";
 }
```

So once the user has been validated, I change the URL of the form to post to, then change the button name. When I then click the submit button nothing happens. How can I submit the form? I tried doing something like form1.submit but obviously that doesn't exist!

Comment: I believe the server control triggers the back code. why not write an if statement. if the submit text changes it should do what you state in the related block.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling

```
Server.Transfer(...);
```

or

```
Response.Redirect(...);
```

Comment: It has to submit the form as it sends through to a secure payment page. I used "myurl2.aspx" as an example. Thanks

Comment: Marked this as correct as it has made me re-do my code to use response.redirect to navigate to a second page.